# How to change SimpleMessageListenerContainer's connectionFactory

Tags: spring-rabbit

I want to change the connectionFactory of SimpleMessageListenerContainer at runtime,in other words,I want to modify the RabbitMQ's connection without restarting the app. although it provided a method "setConnectionFactory",I don't know if I can only do this.What should I do if I want to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `stop()` on the listener container, then `setConnectionFactory()`, then `start()`.

You might want to call `resetConnection()` on the old factory to close its connection.